# Nginx returns 204 instead 200

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have simple erlang web application with cowboy web server. I'm trying to launch it behind nginx reverse proxy.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
        listen 9090;

        default_type text/html;

        location /my_app {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
        }
}
```

If i'm openning `http://localhost:9090/my_app` it's ok, i'm seeing my html page from my web application. But if i'm adding `Content-Type: text/html` header to the cowboy response i'm getting 204 instead 200.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking up what does 204 mean?

Comment: Yes, it returns when request no need body, only meta info, but i send body, it's html page and if i'm trying to request this url with curl it returns normally.